# How to compare msg.data (calldata) data type to an integer data type uint256?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, abi, calldata

As per my [question here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4483y3/how_to_compare_msgdata_bytes_data_type_to_an/):

> I need to compare msg.data (specifically, numbers that are sent with the sendTransaction data object) to a data type of uint256 within my contract.

How is this possible?

Comment: msg.data is of type `calldata`

Comment: I am sorry, but that does not answer my question...

If someone sends a number between 1-100 to my contract using the data object in sendTransaction, how can I compare it to a uint256 within my contract?

Comment: Welcome to the SE :)   I don't know the answer, but I'm sure someone will come along who does. Just trying to be precise so it's easier for that person.

Comment: Thank you I do appreciate it. I do have another account but I have lost my logins deets lol.

Comment: hmm there is no "calldata" type. msg.data type is `bytes`  See global variables https://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/miscellaneous.html

Comment: Yes, it is bytes, but its not immediately castable into other data types like a normal `bytes` type is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Byte-per-byte comparisons. Conversions needed. reddit link is dead. Why do you need to access `msg.data` directly?

EDIT: Convert a uint256 from calldata bytes to a proper uint256 in Solidity: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a734a5d299ffa7b5a834

EDIT: The typing system and posting rules on this site are super weird. Anyways that works. It should always return true.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ethereum SE, your answer appears to be a comment. Could you add some more information about the conversions? I fixed the link by the way.

Comment: I misunderstood.

I thought the only way to send data to a contract was with the data object in the sendTransaction.

Why does this contract not send 1 Finney back to me when I send it this transaction, I cannot for the life of me work out why not:

random.rand.sendTransaction(1,{from: eth.accounts[0], value: web3.toWei(.0001, 'ether'), to: '0x4abc14efad9a7a84a0a9ef6e1a782c43a9e3f550', gas: 500000,  data: web3.fromAscii('message')})

Contract code:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e210a052b6b4c86337c2

Great, no paragraph breaks in comments.

Comment: I upvoted this answer and suggestions for next time: include the actual code itself (since it's not that long) and provide a little more explanation.

Answer (score 5):

The specification for `msg.data` is the [Ethereum Contract ABI](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI).

Here's the code from the answer provided by Andreas:

```
contract ReadConvertUint256Bytes {

    function equal(uint a) constant returns (bool) {
        uint x = 0;
        for (uint i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
            uint b = uint(msg.data[35 - i]);
            x += b * 256**i;
        }
        return a == x;
    }

}
```

It starts reading from the byte indexed at 35, because the first 4 bytes (at index 0 to 3) is the Method ID (see ABI above), and everything in Ethereum internally is big-endian.

Answer (score 3):

Whilst other answers may provide the tools required to answer this question as verbatim, *my* problem was solved because I was not aware of other ways to send parameters to contracts on Ethereum. Namely:
eth.sendTransaction(2{from: eth.accounts[0], value: web3.toWei(5, 'ether'), to: '0xXXXX', gas: 200000,  data: web3.fromAscii('MinedBlock')})

With '2' being the parameter being passed which can then easily be compared inside the contract to other variables. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Since you're passing in value (5 ether), you can check for it with `msg.value`.  ("value" is not part of `msg.data`)

Comment: Also, using [Contract Methods](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-methods) like `myContract.myMethod(5, {from: eth.accounts[0]})` is usually simpler to pass a data (not value) of 5, than direct `eth.sendTransaction`.

Comment: @eth sorry, I updated my answer, I am passing in a parameter in my answer case - 2. Just to confirm, this is not accessible via msg.value. Correct?

Comment: Correct, the "2" is not accessible via msg.value.  But it is simpler to access the "2": if your function is like `myMethod(int8 num)` then num will get the value of 2.